# Using Selenium Opera Driver doesn't start my test execution

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver

I am able to open the Opera browser using Selenium Opera driver.  But I am unable to navigate to any URL using: `driver.get("www.google.com");`

Opera driver starts and doesn't load the given link.

--
Adding the failure trace from comments:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
com.opera.core.systems.scope.exceptions.ResponseNotReceivedException: 
No response in a timely fashion Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18' System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02' Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18' System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
```

Comment: Welcome to SQA, User27.  When you say, "Opera driver starts", do you mean an Opera window actually comes up?

Comment: yes.Browser starts but doesn't load the given URL

Comment: Do you see any errors?  Can you paste your code to the question?

Comment: @Suchit Parikh, 
following is my failure trace.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: com.opera.core.systems.scope.exceptions.ResponseNotReceivedException: No response in a timely fashion
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'
Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_02'

Answer (score 2):

I wrote installation instructions for watir-webdriver: [Opera with watir-webdriver on XP](https://github.com/watir/watirbook/blob/master/installation/windows.md#opera-with-watir-webdriver-on-xp). It was a while ago, but as far as I remember on Windows XP I had to install [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).

Comment: @Zelijko Filipin, Still junit code doesn't connect with opera driver. Opera browser started. But couldn't start my url load.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Initialize the opera driver ....

WebDriver driver;
Selenium selenium;
driver = new OperaDriver();
selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "url here");
```

Comment: Sakib, you don't really give enough information here for your answer to be really good, particularly for such an old question. It seems too obvious for the original poster to have missed.